# ActiveRecord undefined method `has_key?' for nil:NilClass error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, vagrant

I have a fairly simple forms-over-data Rails app that calls a remote MySql 5.5 db. Using Rails 3.2.21, Ruby 1.9.3.

One of the pages in the app is throwing the following error:

```
NoMethodError in GvpController#input
   undefined method `has_key?' for nil:NilClass
   app/controllers/gvp_controller.rb:9:in `input'
```

Here is the offending code from the controller:

```
class GvpController < ApplicationController
  def input
    # irrelevant stuff
    @list =  Vendor.gvp_vendor_names.map { |x| x.vendor_name }
    # more irrelevant stuff
  end      
  # other irrelevant methods
end
```

I'm assuming the call to gvp_vendor_names is returning nil.

Here is the Vendor model class:

```
class Vendor < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection :vendor_sql
  self.table_name = 'reporting_dw.vp_vendor_mapping'
  scope :gvp_vendor_names, -> {
    select('reporting_dw.vp_vendor_mapping.vendor_name')}
end
```

I have searched other posts with this error message and so far haven't found one that seems relevant. I am not overriding the initialize method (one possible cause) and I think the syntax is correct (another).

As an additional wrinkle, I am using vagrant for development, so I thought perhaps I'm not successfully communicating with the database from the vagrant box - maybe an ssh or permissions issue. To test it, I opened an ssh session on the vagrant box, successfully connected with the db via command line ran a select statement and lo and behold, get the full list of results I was expecting. I also tried it with mysql workbench via ssh and had no problems. So, it seems I can communicate remotely with the db, execute queries against it, have the proper permissions etc.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what the problem might be?

Comment: I don't see any code with `has_key?` in it?

Comment: I would agree with your assumption __I'm assuming the call to gvp_vendor_names is returning nil__.  Once you confirm this, you will need to decide how to protect against it (generally make it so it can never return Nil or adding `if Vendor.gvp_vendor_names` to the end of that line).  Or perhaps something more elegant.

Comment: why not just make a method rather than a scope e.g. `def self.gvp_vendor_names;pluck(:vendor_name);end`? Also why are you expecting `has_key?` which is a `Hash` method from a scope in which you are expecting it to return an `ActiveRecord::Relation` using `select`?

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you haven't any value on your DB tables. That's why the issue arise in controller action block during you call `gvp_vendor_names` mapped value `vendor_name`

You should handle this type of case by checking the object value rather than accessing firstclass

```
GvpController < ApplicationController
  def input
    # irrelevant stuff
    @list =  Vendor.gvp_vendor_names.map { |x| x.vendor_name if x.present?}
    # more irrelevant stuff
  end      
  # other irrelevant methods
end
```

In this way you need to compact the nil value. So use this finally if you want to handle the scenario from controller:

```
class GvpController < ApplicationController
  def input
    # irrelevant stuff
    @list =  Vendor.gvp_vendor_names.map { |x| x.vendor_name if x.present?}.compact
    # more irrelevant stuff
  end      
  # other irrelevant methods
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The real problem may just be that I'm a Rails/ActiveRecord n00b. After a little more experimentation, I found the following changes corrected the error.

In the model I added attr_accessible and then used engineersmnky's suggestion of using a method rather than scope, as follows:

```
class Vendor < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection :vendor_sql 
  attr_accessible :vendor_name
  self.table_name = 'reporting_dw.vp_vendor_mapping'

  def self.gvp_vendor_names
    pluck(:vendor_name).sort
  end
end
```

Then in the controller:

```
class GvpController < ApplicationController
  def input
    #irrelevant stuff
    @list = Vendor.gvp_vendor_names 
    #irrelevant stuff
  end
end
```

That fixed it. Thank you everyone for the suggestions!